# How to return just created row with its association with sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

with the `create()` method I get the just created row back is there a way to get its associations also back.

like the `include` option we get  with `findAll`

for example I have this output on `create`

```
 {
    "id": 62,
    "product_id": 1, // Association
    "quantity": "20",
    "user_id": 1,  // Association
    "updatedAt": "2021-06-04T12:20:33.370Z",
    "createdAt": "2021-06-04T12:20:33.370Z"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, to achieve this simply run a second query to retrieve the newly created object like below:

```
Order.create({
      productId,
      quantity,
      userId
    }).then((newOrder) => {
      Order.findAll({
        where: { orderId: newOrder.orderId },
        include: [
          {
            model: Product //association
          },
          {
            model: User //association
          }
        ]
      }).then((order) => {
        console.log('new order', order);
      });
    });
```

If there is anyone that knows of a better way to retrieve the newly created object, i would also appreciate the solution.